# How to remove white background that is behind my arrow on my bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I've been trying to make a video carousel with Bootstrap 5 and an issue that I'm trying to resolve is removing the white background that pops up when I hover over the arrow. Normally, it shouldn't have a background, but for some reason, it does.

*click to enlarge*

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```css
.heading2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading2">
  <h3>Film/Video Editing Projects</h3>
  <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
  <div id="carouselVideoExample" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
           <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/blue/white.mp4?text=video 1" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
          <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/black/white.mp4?text=video+2" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
          <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/green/white.mp4?text=video+3" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Inner -->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel wrapper -->`

  <!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, if i copy/paste your code and loads latest ccss/js  library of bootstrap, there seems to be no troubles , minor the fact that i have not any mp4 files to test / link to your code. I'll update your question with a snippet of your codes. You can deny it or update it to your convenience

Answer (score 1):

Two separate CDNs, one with version 5.0.2 and the other with version 5.3.2, are the sources of the two inclusions of Bootstrap. Utilizing a single version is preferable to avoid such conflicts. In this scenario, 5.3.2 is the most recent version I advise utilizing.
Here is the solution :-

```css
  .heading2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }
  .carousel-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .carousel-control-prev:hover,
  .carousel-control-next:hover {
      background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

```html
<!--You can try using only one Bootstrap latest version.-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
<div class="heading2">
  <h3>Film/Video Editing Projects</h3>
  <div id="carouselVideoExample" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
          <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/blue/white.mp4?text=video 1" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
          <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/black/white.mp4?text=video+2" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls class="d-block w-100">
          <source src="https://placehold.co/3840x2160/green/white.mp4?text=video+3" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselVideoExample" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```